# How to dynamically passing value from view to controller to fetch a different value

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter, I have passed an array from controller to view

Controller code:

```
$data['x'] = $this->home_model->get_latest_five_rows();
$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('app/'.$page, $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
```

View code:

```
<? foreach ($x as $listing): ?>
Posted by <a href="/users/profile/<? echo $listing['by_user_id']; ?>"><? echo $listing['by_user_id']; ?></a>
```

I want to fetch the name of the user from "$listing['by_user_id']". How do I achieve this?

Based on comments modified it accordingly but no success

Code in view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "users/user_name",
data: {send: <? echo $job_listing['by_user_id']; ?>},
success: function(value) {

 }
 });
 </script>
```

Controller:

```
public function user_name($id) {
    $data['user_name'] = $this->user_model->get_user_name($this->post('id'));
    $this->load->view('app/', $data);
}
```

Model code:

```
public function get_user_name($id) {

    $query ="select user_full_name from app_users where id = ".$id;
    $res = $this->db->query($query);               
    return $res->result_array();
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any error. And why don't use query to get name directly from the controller function

Comment: for this you need an ajax request fired on controller , everytime link is clicked

Comment: Ok. Will try it out and post the solution.

Comment: You are not really supposed to pass data to controllers from a view (well, not unless it is a **user action** that matches a routing pattern). If the view received data from the controller, then, by definition, the value you are looking for _should_ exist in the controller at some time.

Comment: is it problem Solved?

Answer (score 0):

You are not really supposed to pass data to controllers from a view (well, not unless it is a **user action** that matches a routing pattern, but that is a different question of interpreting MVC for web).

If the view received data from the controller, then, by definition, the value you are looking for *should* exist in the controller at some time.

`$data['x']` in controller *equals to* (by value or by reference) `$x` in your view.

That is, if you do this in your view:

```
foreach ($x as $listing)
{
    $user_id = $listing['by_user_id'];
}
```

... then, in the context of the structure of the variable, it is equivalent to this in your controller:

```
foreach ($data['x'] as $listing)
{
    $user_id = $listing['by_user_id'];
}
```

Comment: by_user_id is the id of the user who submitted the row. I have the user name and other details stored in a different table. what do I do in that case?

Comment: I assume you either do an `inner join` in your model, or separate model calls using that ID - it's your choice, and I don't know your entire system.